# Sometimes the timer script fails to produce a sound when the time runs out

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, time

I am currently preparing for an exam that requires me to solve a large number of questions in a short amount of time. To increase my speed, I have created a simple Python program using tkinter that generates a sound after every 50 seconds and repeats itself. However, I have noticed that the program works well for a few minutes, but after that, it sometimes fails to produce the sound when the timer runs out and just resets the clock.

```
import time,winsound
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("50 sec timer")
Second=StringVar()
Second.set("50")
Second_entry= Entry(root, width=3, font=("Comic Sans MS",40,""),fg='blue',textvariable=Second)
Second_entry.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W+E)

def OK(n=None):
    temp = 50   #Change this if you want to change time 
    while temp >-1:
        Second.set("{0:2d}".format(temp))
        root.update()
        time.sleep(1)
        if (temp == 0):
            winsound.Beep(840,1200)   # change this if your want your alarm to be louder or longer (frequency,time(in millisecond))
            return OK()
        temp -= 1

button = Button(root, text=' countdown', bd='5', font=("Comic Sans MS",30,""),fg='blue',command= OK)
button.grid(row=1,column=0)

root.bind('<space>',OK)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You would probably benefit from using the `after` and `update_idletasks` method, `sleep` is almost never what you want with `tkinter`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that leverages tkinter's built-in `after` method

```
time = 50  # declare a 'time' variable in the global scope
second = StringVar()
second.set(time)  # string conversion is handled automatically here - bonus!


def OK(n=None):  # I'm not sure what 'n' is used for, but I don't think you need it...
    global time  # let this function modify the value of 'time'
    time -= 1  # decrement the time value
    second.set(f'{time:02d}')  # update the label
    timer = root.after(1000, OK)  # call this function again after 1000mS
    if time <= 0:  # no time left
        winsound.Beep(840, 1200)  # BEEP!
        time = 50  # reset!
```

As Rory's comment alluded, you should avoid using `sleep` in tkinter apps because the GUI will hang while `sleep`ing. As a general rule, it's also better to use `update_idletasks()` rather than `update()`, though I don't think you really need either of those here.

Also, capitalized names like `StringVar` are typically reserved for classes, while variables are usually written in `snake_case` with lowercase letters, e.g.: `second_entry`, FWIW